# Dynamic Table Name in Excel Lambda Function with Structured References without INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to define an excel lambda function that takes a parameter that acts as a "dynamic" name for a table, that is then used in a structured reference, **without using the INDIRECT function**?
My hope is to be able to define a helper method that allows users to, in effect, use a table to define a dictionary structure with a string as the key and a tuple as the value, and then, to pluck out specific pieces of that tuple.

An example table named "Variables" is below:

| Variable | Initial Value | Initial Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pressure | 1 | atm |
| Volume | 4 | L |
| mass | 10 | g |
| Temperature | 30 | C |
| Rgas | 0.7 | atm*L/g*C |

And my desired behaviour is to be able to define a lambda that users can then call like so:

`=l.Variable("Variables","mass","Initial Value")`

(with the result being `10`)

So far though, I can only achieve this particular interface by employing the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=LAMBDA(Table,Var,Prop,
    INDEX(
        INDIRECT(Table & "[#All]"),
        MATCH(Var,INDIRECT(Table & "[[#All],[Variable]]"),0),
        MATCH(Prop,INDIRECT(Table & "[#Headers]"),0)
    )
)
```

If I instead want to avoid usage of `INDIRECT`, I have to hard-code the specific table name:

```
=LAMBDA(Var,Prop,
    INDEX(
        Variables[#All],
        MATCH(Var,Variables[[#All],[Variable]],0),
        MATCH(Prop,Variables[#Headers],0)
    )
)
```

Am I out of luck? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

I have linked to a workbook that uses both the hard-coded approach and the `INDIRECT` approach below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/344rfrrzhjjr6z2/superuser-lambda-question.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Just be aware that as far as I know, LAMBDA is not yet available in mainstream Excel 365, and only available to users who opt in to "Office Insiders".

Comment: As for your question, if you have a defined number of tables, you can use `CHOOSE(MATCH(var, {"Variables", "Things", "Bobs"}, 0),  INDEX(Variables[#all]...), INDEX(Things[#all]...), INDEX(Bobs[#all]...))`

Comment: Also, shame on you for not liking Excel! Trying to implement your pythony tuples in Excel I see :)

Comment: I like the `CHOOSE` approach, at least for scenarios where the number of tables is finite :) it still introduces some code duplication, but that's hidden from users by default. Thanks!

Comment: Just a though - why use multiple tables at all? Why not just use one table, with "nested tables" if you will. Column names e.g. "Category/Table name", "Variable", "Value", "Unit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> takes a parameter that acts as a "dynamic" name for a table

The best way in Excel to convert a text parameter to a range is to use INDIRECT function.
(other ways are OFFSET and custom VBA function, however in your case both would be more complicated)

However you can still improve your formula using FILTER, instead of INDEX and MATCH.

Below example shows only part of your desired formula as my Excel doesn't yet have LAMBDA.

`=FILTER(INDIRECT(E1&"["&G1&"]"),INDIRECT(E1&"[Variable]")=F1)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can look up arbitrary data from a table without INDIRECT fairly easily.  You just need to pass the full table reference with the [#All] qualifier instead of just the table name as a string, and extract the [#Header] and [#Data] sections yourself using INDEX.

I've broken this up into multiple lambdas, which is how I would implement it for myself.  I also included some error checking.

You could tweak as needed to work exactly how you want.

```
getTableColumn = lambda(tableall, colname, let(
   header, index(tableall, 1, 0),
   data, let(rcount, rows(tableall), index(tableall, 2, 0):index(tableall, rcount, 0)),
   colIndex, xmatch(colname, header),
   if(isnumber(colIndex), index(data, 0, colIndex), "column not found")));

TableLookup = lambda(tableAll, keyColName, dataColName, keyVal, let(
   keyCol, getTableColumn(tableAll, keyColName),
   dataCol, getTableColumn(tableAll, dataColName),
   keyFound, index(keyCol, 1)<>"column not found",
   dataFound, index(dataCol, 1)<>"column not found",
   ifs(
       not(keyFound), "key column not found",
       not(dataFound), "data column not found",
       and(keyFound, dataFound), xlookup(keyVal, keyCol, dataCol, "key not found"))
    ));
```

So using this lambda for your original example:

```
=TableLookup(Variable[#All], "Variable", "Initial Value", "mass")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Non-volatile method to INDEX into different Tables or Sheets**

The only way to INDEX into different tables using a text *variable* is to use INDIRECT as per the question. The reason to avoid INDIRECT of course is because it is volatile, meaning it will recalculate at every possible opportunity (INDIRECT can refer to any cell, and is thus dependent on every cell). Volatile functions can impact performance, especially for large workbooks.

For a finite predefined number of tables or sheets you can use CHOOSE and LET (LET requires Excel 365). For tables:

```
=LET(tableall,CHOOSE(MATCH(table,{"Table1","Table2","Table3"},0),Table1[#All],Table2[#All],Table3[#All]),INDEX(tableall,MATCH(var,INDEX(tableall,,1),0),MATCH(prop,INDEX(tableall,1,),0)))
```

Where *var* is the lookup value in the first column of the table, and *prop* is the matching header column.

If you need specific table columns your can extend LET with multiple variables e.g.:

```
=LET(tableindex,MATCH(table,{"Table1","Table2","Table3"},0),tableall,CHOOSE(tableindex,Table1[#All],Table2[#All],Table3[#All]),tablehdr,CHOOSE(tableindex,Table1[#Headers],Table2[#Headers],Table3[#Headers]),INDEX(tableall,MATCH(var,INDEX(tableall,,1),0),MATCH(prop,tablehdr,0)))
```

Or if you only need a VLOOKUP and not a full INDEX:

```
=LET(tableall,CHOOSE(MATCH(table,{"Table1","Table2","Table3"},0),Table1[#All],Table2[#All],Table3[#All]),INDEX(tableall,VLOOKUP(var,tableall,MATCH(prop,INDEX(tableall,1,),0),FALSE))
```

And lastly once LAMDA makes it into the production version of Excel 365, you can basically define the above as a named range function and call it with parameters e.g. `=TABLEINDEX("Table1","Mass","Initial Value")`

And as an FYI, you can do the same to dynamically address different  Sheets in a non-volatile way:

```
=LET(sheet,CHOOSE(MATCH(sheetname,{"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"},0),Sheet1!$1:$10000,Sheet2!$1:$10000,Sheet3!$1:$10000),INDEX(sheet, i, j))
```

where *sheetname* is the sheetname as a textvalue, *i* and *j* are row and column indexes.

PS. If you don't have Excel 365, the above can all be done without LET, you just need to substitute/duplicate the formulae for each named LET variable in the main formula (more computationally intensive).